# How do I set the vim plugin youCompleteMe to c++ and python?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, youcompleteme

I want to configure my vim file to set youcompleteme to autocomplete my cpp and .py files, but I don know how do this at the same time.

Comment: YCM does not require special settings for different file types, what exactly do you want? If you want example of .vimrc, I can write my, since I use YCM for C++ and python too.

Comment: Can you share your .vimrc configuration please

Answer (score 3):

~/.vimrc

```
let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/simple_ycm_extra_conf.py'
let g:ycm_seed_identifiers_with_syntax = 1
set completeopt=menu

" make YCM compatible with UltiSnips (using <Ctrl-N>, <Ctrl-P>)
let g:ycm_key_list_select_completion=[]
let g:ycm_key_list_previous_completion=[]

" commands mappings
nnoremap <F1> :pclose<CR>:silent YcmCompleter GetDoc<CR>
nnoremap <S-F1> :pclose<CR>
nnoremap <C-F1> :YcmCompleter GetType<CR>
nnoremap <F9> :YcmCompleter GoTo<CR>
nnoremap <S-F9> :YcmCompleter GoToReferences<CR>
nnoremap <F10> :YcmCompleter FixIt<CR>

let g:ycm_use_clangd = 1
```

`~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/simple_ycm_extra_conf.py` used as default YCM build rules for C++. For more complex projects I recommend use cmake as described in YCM manual. Also note that clangd YCM compilation allows you to use more commands.

```
def Settings( **kwargs ):
  return {
    'flags': [ '-x', 'c++', '-Wall', '-Wextra', '-Werror' ],
  }
```